# How do I make my C program allow the user to create his own filename?

Tags: c, file-io

So I'm coding a program which is a grading system for a very small community college. 
I want to create new accounts for each user (these accounts are to be stored in separate files), but I don't see how to do this. I tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```
    FILE *(" %s", username);

    (" %s", username)=fopen((" %s", username),"w");
    fprintf((" %s", username),"%s\n", username);
    fprintf((" %s", username),"%s", password);
    fclose((" %s", username));
```

I was trying to set the user's username as the filename, but I don't see how that would work.

Comment: What is `FILE *(" %s", username);` ????

Comment: Yh lol, I know it isn't, but I tried just in case.

Comment: Next time you could push randomly keyboard push buttons and then ask: Could you write my code?

Comment: @APMullings no offense intended, but if your abilities are unadvanced enough that you feel it acceptable to have tried that "just in case", this project is well beyond your abilities.

Comment: Please read a C book! just in case ... you want to write C programs.

Comment: Well I guess we all have to start somewhere right?

Comment: Yeah, we do have to start somewhere, but when you're capable of chapter 1 and you're attempting an assignment from chapter 10, you're starting in the wrong place.

Comment: @APMullings Yes , but to start correctly and informatively is well needed :-)

Comment: @APMullings, you could start [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html), or [here](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=how+to+open+a+file+in+c), or possibly [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=613868) which has an exact answer you're looking for .. C is a powerful language and SO is not a place to learn how to code but to help you understand what you're not grasping. Please [take a tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of how to ask relevant questions .. If you've tried something and it's not working, please rephrase your question or it might be closed.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't do it like that in `C`. I'll not be writing a full code, but will happily provide the way to get it done.

1. Define an array long enough to store the desired filename.
2. Ask for user input for the filename and store it into the array.
3. Define a `FILE *` variable.
4. Call `fopen()` with the array (containing filename) and the required mode. Store the return value of the call to the variable.
5. Check for the success of the `fopen()` call.
6. use the `FILE *` variable as usual to perform the related operations `fprintf()`/ `fscanf()`/`fgets()`.